# Change mac-address with Netconf

Tags: netconf

I am playing around with Netconf and I try to do some configurations with the openconfig yang models. I use ncclient to send the configuration and netconfd from the yuma123 project to simulate a network device.
I am able to write configurations with the openconfig-interfaces yang model. Now I also added the openconfig-if-ethernet yang model to my tests. Here the problem begins.
The xml file which I send to the "device" looks like this:

```
    <interfaces xmlns="http://openconfig.net/yang/interfaces">
        <interface>
            <name>Eth1/1</name>
            <config>
                <name>Eth1/1</name>
                <type xmlns:ianaift="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:iana-if-type">ianaift:ethernetCsmacd</type>
                <description>Test description</description>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </config>
            <subinterfaces>
                <subinterface>
                    <index>0</index>
                    <config>
                        <index>0</index>
                        <description>Test description</description>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </config>
                </subinterface>
            </subinterfaces>
            <ethernet xmlns="http://openconfig.net/yang/interfaces/ethernet"><config>
                    <mac-address>aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa</mac-address>
                </config>
            </ethernet>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
</config>
```

The error which I receive in netconfd:

```
rpc-error: (333) invalid-value L:protocol S:error app-tag:pattern-test-failed
   path:/nc:rpc/nc:edit-config/nc:config/oc-if:interfaces/oc-if:interface[oc-if:name='Eth1/1']/oc-eth:ethernet/oc-eth:config/oc-eth:mac-address lang:en
  msg:pattern match failed
  error-info: bad-value T:string = aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa
  error-info: error-number T:uint32 = 333
```

and

```
<rpc-reply xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0"
  message-id="urn:uuid:4be8c4c5-3164-4998-84b5-02c3bccf61e9"
  xmlns:oc-eth="http://openconfig.net/yang/interfaces/ethernet"
  xmlns:oc-if="http://openconfig.net/yang/interfaces"
  xmlns:ncx="http://netconfcentral.org/ns/yuma-ncx"
  xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
  <rpc-error>
    <error-type>protocol</error-type>
    <error-tag>invalid-value</error-tag>
    <error-severity>error</error-severity>
    <error-app-tag>pattern-test-failed</error-app-tag>
    <error-path>/nc:rpc/nc:edit-config/nc:config/oc-if:interfaces/oc-if:interface[oc-if:name='Eth1/1']/oc-eth:ethernet/oc-eth:config/oc-eth:mac-address</error-path>
    <error-message xml:lang="en">pattern match failed</error-message>
    <error-info>
      <bad-value xmlns="http://netconfcentral.org/ns/yuma-ncx">aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa</bad-value>
      <error-number xmlns="http://netconfcentral.org/ns/yuma-ncx">333</error-number>
    </error-info>
  </rpc-error>
```

From my understanding, this means that the format of the mac-address is not correct.

Is there something wrong with the xml file which I send to the device?

Thank you

Remo

Comment: Because there is no standard for the representation of MAC addresses (there are both 48- and 64-bit MAC addresses, different vendors may use different representations, including on different devices made by the same vendor (Cisco has different representations for routers and switches). See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/56142/8499) about that.